# custom directive injection is not working in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I've done custom directive for frag and drop file upload and put it on a module but it is not working as expected. It is showing error in console and copying that as well.

[image: Error Description from console]
Could any one tell where i went wrong?

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Angular Js Page</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<style>

div[dropzone] {
    border: 2px dashed #bbb;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font: 20pt bold;
    color: #bbb;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body ng-app="Myapp">

<div dropzone>Drop Files Here</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module("Myapp", ['dropzone']);

    app.directive("dropzone", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "A",
        link: function (scope, elem) {
            elem.bind('drop', function(evt) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
                evt.preventDefault();

                var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
                for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);

                    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                        return function(e) {
                            var newFile = { name : theFile.name,
                                type : theFile.type,
                                size : theFile.size,
                                lastModifiedDate : theFile.lastModifiedDate
                            }

                            scope.addfile(newFile);
                        };
                    })(f);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you adding `dropzone` as a dependency of `Myapp` module. Its a directive. You need not to inject it.

Comment: you dont need to inject module ,if you have not created one .remove  'dropzone' from  var app = angular.module("Myapp", ['dropzone']); line then it will work

Answer (score 0):

dropzone is not a different module. You can't inject it to your Myapp module.

it is a directive living inside myApp. You need to read more about angular directives and modules

change

```
var app = angular.module("Myapp", ['dropzone']);
```

to

```
var app = angular.module("Myapp");
```

it'll probably work